# How to count incoming links?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents looking like this:

```
{
    "url" : "http://example.com",
    "links" : [
        "http://example.com/foo",
        "http://example.com/bar"
    ]
},
{
    "url" : "http://example.com/foo",
    "links" : [
        "http://example.com/bar"
    ]
},
{
    "url" : "http://example.com/lost",
    "links" : [
        "http://example.com/bar"
    ]
},
{
    "url" : "http://example.com/bar",
    "links" : []
}
```

How to aggregate by url and count the number of **incoming** links:

```
{
    "url": http://example.com,
    "count" : 0
},
{
    "url": http://example.com/lost,
    "count" : 0
},
{
    "url": http://example.com/foo,
    "count" : 1
},
{
    "url": http://example.com/bar,
    "count" : 3
}
```

Do you have any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is tricky as you want to count the *incoming* links. You can achieve the desired result by using [map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/):

The map stage will emit a "1" for every link targetted by the currently examined URL. In addition, to ensure that every *source* URL is in the result set, I emit a "0" for the source link:

```
map = function() {
    for (var idx = 0; idx < this.links.length; idx++) {
        emit(this.links[idx], 1)
    }
    emit(this.url, 0) // this ensure that all URL are in the output set
}
```

After that, your reduce step is only a matter of summing multiple values if any:

```
reduce = function(key, values) {
    return values.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;});
}
```

Given you sample data set:

```
> db.test.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:{inline:1}})
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "http://example.com",
            "value" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : "http://example.com/bar",
            "value" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : "http://example.com/foo",
            "value" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "http://example.com/lost",
            "value" : 0
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 1,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 4,
        "emit" : 8,
        "reduce" : 2,
        "output" : 4
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to achieve the desired result. The following aggregation pipeline will give you that:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$links"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$url",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "url": "$_id",
            "count": 1
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "count" : 1,
            "url" : "http://example.com/lost"
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 1,
            "url" : "http://example.com/foo"
        }, 
        {
            "count" : 2,
            "url" : "http://example.com"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

As I did not see that you want to count the number of **incoming** links, the aggregation above won't work. However, to get the aggregation based on that criteria then change the grouping to group by the `links` array elements and create an output collection as the final aggregation pipeline using the [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out) operator. This will be necessary to query the original collection for empty incoming links array and update the results collection accordingly. For example:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$links"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$links",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "url": "$_id",
            "count": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$out": "results"
    }
])
```

In the results collection, you can then update the documents using a combination of [**`map()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map) and [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) cursor methods to get an array of urls that have a count and iterating over the original collection looking for documents where the url is not the before-mentioned array:

```
var urlsWithCount = db.results.find().map(function(u){ return u.url });
db.test.find({"url": {"$nin": urlsWithCount}}).forEach(function(doc){
    var obj = {};
    obj.url = doc.url;
    obj.count = 0;
    db.results.save(obj);   
});    


db.results.find();
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5555c1c49cd8fa39c7971e54"),
    "count" : 3,
    "url" : "http://example.com/bar"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5555c1c49cd8fa39c7971e55"),
    "count" : 1,
    "url" : "http://example.com/foo"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5555c3829bbec0dd0344e4ac"),
    "url" : "http://example.com",
    "count" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5555c3829bbec0dd0344e4ad"),
    "url" : "http://example.com/lost",
    "count" : 0
}
```

Comment: This is much more complicated than that as the OP want the count of _back_ links (incoming" links) !

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Thanks for pointing that out, couldn't catch that. I have my updated answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Nice trick, but you need write access to the DB. As on myself, the only solution I found was by using map-reduce. Fits nicely with the OP issue though ;)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I absolutely agree, a +1 from me!